# TFS e Source Tree

Tags: team-foundation-server

Estou usando o TFS como repositório, mas tudo tenho que fazer no Source Tree porque no Visual Studio 2013 não aparece o Explorer onde eu consigo fazer um merge ou verificar a arvore de arquivos.

Tem algum plugin ou tem como eu resolver isso para poder utilizar o Visual Studio ?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Git é acessível através do Team Explorer no Visual Studio. Ele é instalado por padrão, e inicialmente, fica no mesmo grupo de de abas com o Explorer. Existe ferramentas necessárias que devem ser instaladas através do setup do VS ou quando é feita a instalação da IDE. Encontram-se na sessão "3°th Party...".
Abrindo o projeto ele identifica que está no Git e apresenta as ferramentas.

Comment: Você saberia me informar o link para eu instalar as ferramentas ?

Comment: Rode novamente o setup de instalação.